# How to create desktop shortcut passing custom arguments?

Tags: linux, kde-plasma

I have KDE 5.20.5 and would like to create a desktop shortcut for launching Chromium passing custom  command line arguments to it.

Initially, I've right-clicked on a Launcher Chromium menu entry -> `Add to Desktop...` and the shortcut got created. However, it's just a symlink to `/usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop` and I can't modify it.

Then, I've tried to copy that `/usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop` onto my desktop manually so I could modify the copy and not touch the original. However even before editing it, it 's unable to launch Chromium. It displays the following message box when double-clicked:

> Unknown error code 100 You are not authorized to execute this file.
> Please send a full bug report at https://bugs.kde.org.

I've sweated googling an answer to such the basic question: **what is correct \ recommended way of creating a modifiable desktop shortcut based on a Launcher menu entry in KDE Plasma?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the copied *chromium.desktop* file executable. With *Dolphin* file manager: right-click on your *.desktop* file → `Properties` → `Permissions` tab → check `Is executable` checkbox.

> Alternatively, from the folder with your *.desktop* file, you can run:
>
> ```
> chmod 755 chromium.desktop
> ```

Now it should be able to launch Chromium.

To add a custom argument(-s) to the launcher - back in the `Properties` of your .desktop file go to the `Application` tab and add your argument(-s) to the `Command` field after the path to the executable, for example:

```
/usr/bin/chromium --profile-directory="Default"
```

While we are at the `Application` tab, you may want to change the `Name` field to something like "Chromium w/args" to help distinguish launchers later on.

> As an option, you can edit the *.desktop* file by opening it with a text editor of your preference. To edit the launch command, navigate to the `[Desktop Entry]` group header, under which locate the line starting with `Exec=` and add custom arguments to it.
>
> To edit the name of the launcher, under the same header locate lines starting with `Name=` (`Name[xx_XX]=`, e.g. `Name[en_US]=` for localized names) and alter them as you wish.
>
> More information on Desktop Entries can be found in its [specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) or on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries)

To add your new launcher to the application menus (for the current user) - move *.desktop* file to the

```
~/.local/share/applications/
```

Now your launcher will be available in Application Launcher and Krunner.

If you want the new launcher to co-exist with the original (instead of overriding it), you should rename the *.desktop* file to something like *chromium_args.desktop*.

Comment: Thank you! Everything has worked except that I don't have  the `Name` field on the `Application` tab. So I can't change the text displayed under the icon on the desktop. Do you actually have that field?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov Yes, I have that field using Dolphin 20.12.3. But you always can edit name (and everything else) by opening .desktop file with any text editor. Updated my answer to describe that.

Comment: running `chmod 744 app.desktop` on app.desktop file in `/usr/share/app-location/app.desktop` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command at root directory :

```
ln -s $PWD ~/Desktop/
```

Comment: Create a link to the root directory `/` at the desktop? Why?